# multiple copies of a file in .cab file

Tags: windows, windows-installer

How can I put duplicate copy of a file in a cabinet(.cab) file (both of the files are from same source) ? is there any Cabinet API method supporting this thing ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't think it's possible. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Basically I want to put one of the files(assemblies) into the local file system and the other into the GAC while installation. Also To build the MSI I am not using any third party tools such as Wise for windows Installer , Wix etc. If I use any one of these then my life would have been easy. Instead that I have an CreateMSI  application which creates MSI for me. so to get my work done I need to have one extra copy of the assembly in .cab file.